# VueJS - how to delay data item updating?

Tags: vuejs2

Not sure how to title this question, but here's my situation: I have an array of objects. Among other fields, the objects have a `date_beginning` and a `date_ending` field. In presenting my array of objects, I break them into two groups -- first group has a value in *only* the `date_beginning` while the second group has a value in *both* the `date_beginning` **and** the `date_ending` fields.

Something like:

```
// Only date_beginning present
Object 1
Object 2
Object 3

// Has both date_beginning and date_ending
Object 4
Object 5
Object 6
Object 7
```

Now, I have an `Edit` button on each array item that, when clicked, will present a form for the user to edit *both* dates. The user edits the dates, then hits `SAVE` and the app will issue a `PATCH` request to the backend server to update the record in the database.

**Here's my problem:**

If a user enters a date in the `date_ending` in any object in the first group, as soon as the user finishes entering the date, the object is *immediately* moved to the second list. I understand this is VueJS "doing its job". But, the problem this creates is that the user hasn't had a chance to click "Save" which means it hasn't been saved to the backend, and further the object they just edited is now in a different list, so they have to go find it again to continue editing the object and to click Save.

Hopefully that makes sense. So I'm trying to figure out a better way to somehow delay the update to the object itself, or hide this update from VueJS somehow so that the object doesn't get auto-sorted into the second list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't update the object that is being rendered until you get the response back from the server. This may mean when you are editing the object you need to make a copy of the original.

Comment: @Bert is right, update the object only after the ajax call succeeds, else don't update the object.

Comment: @Bert So only when the user clicks "Edit" then make a copy of the object, and put that copy into the v-model of all the form inputs. After clicking "Save" and getting a success response, then copy that *copy* back to the object within the `data` section of the component?

Comment: It depends. If your component actually performs the patch, then you can use v-model on the component and only emit changes on success (v-model works by listening for the `input` event).

Comment: @Bert Yes, the component performs the patch. However, the object in question is passed to the component via `props`. So I can delay the emitting of the update on success of the `patch` request? So the object itself won't be auto-moved to the second list (as described in my question) until after I've received the success response back from the server? I'll have to look into how to do that, didn't know that was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a component that does what I mention in the comments above.

```
Vue.component("edit-dates", {
  props: ["value"],
  template:`
    <div>
      <input v-model="internalDates.date_beginning" type="date">
      <input v-model="internalDates.date_ending" type="date">
      <br>
      <button @click="save">Save</button>
    <div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      internalDates: Object.assign({}, this.value)
    }
  },
  watch:{
    value(newVal){ this.internalDates = Object.assign({}, newVal)}
  },
  methods:{
    save(){
      // simulate an ajax patch
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$emit('input', this.internalDates)
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
})
```

This component implements support for `v-model`. When the value is passed in, a copy of that object is created. **Important note**: `Object.assign` does a shallow copy, so if you have a deeper nested object, you will need to use a method for copying the object that works for deeply nested objects. Also, whenever the value is updated, a copy is made.

Since the component is working off a copy of the data, the component can *choose* when to $emit the updated value. In the above example, an ajax call is simulated with setTimeout and the update is only emitted when the time has elapsed.

Here is a [codepen demonstrating](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/vJpVpM?editors=1010) the component.

Comment: Nice, I'll give this a try and see if it will address my situation. Thanks